# Python & BS4: Start searching for term starting at certain div

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Python 2.7.6 + BeautifulSoup 4 + requests noob here.

My question concerns searching through contents of div-classes, i.e. like [on this site](http://www.clever-tanken.de/tankstelle_liste?spritsorte=5&ort=Frankfurt&r=5.0&sort=p).
I only want to use the content of a line when each column contains information. 
I was able to write a piece of code that extracts the content of the div-class of the fuelprice (which in on the website is column 1). Sometimes the gas stations that are listed first are closed and no price appears. So my code grabs the first div that contains a price actually.

```
pricediv = soup.find("div", {"class": "price"})
price = pricediv.text
```

Next, I want to grab the name and address of the gas station I extracted the price from, which are contained in two further div classes. How can I make

```
location = soup.find("div", {"class": "location_name"})
```

start searching at the position of the div-class that contained the gas price I extracted earlier? Otherwise, if i.e. the first two gas stations are closed, my variable pricediv will contain the gas price of the third gas station. But if I run the code to find the location (as above), it will return the very first location (of the closed gas station number 1). So I want it to start looking for the location div right after the price-div.

I hope I made clear what I am looking for and that somebody may have a hint for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you want `find_all` not `find`, your link is giving me a 501 error also

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @PadraicCunningham, I used 'find' because I just want to use the first (and therefor cheapest) price on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provided, your **price** div is a child of **priceblock div** which again is a child of **price_entry_table div**, so in order to locate the **div** you want, you need to use `parent`, this is what it should look like:

```
pricediv = soup.find('div', {'class': 'price'})
price = pricediv.text
# use parent.parent to get to the price_entry_table div, then find location_name
locationdiv = pricediv.parent.parent.find('div', {'class': 'location_name'})
location = locationdiv.text
print price, location

# sample result
1.379 Tankstelle Wagner/DBV Würzburg
```

Also, if you need to access all `div`s, you may want to use `findAll` like @PadraicCunningham advised, something like this:

```
for pricediv in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'price'}):
    price = pricediv.text
    ... do your remaining code here ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Anzel, `parent` works like a charm. I used `find` instead of `find_all` to find only the first (cheapest) price on the list, since `find_all` would return every price on the page. Again, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @LaMigra, ah now I see why you use `find` for the first record. Glad it helps :)